# What script would you write to run a basic "Hello world" immediately an Apache server is launched?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, redhat

Trying to add it to my user data on the AWS instance I created via Red Hat.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I keep landing on the Red Hat homepage.

This is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
#sudo yum install httpd -y
sudo service httpd start
sudo chkconfig httpd on
cd /var/www/html
echo"<html><h1>This is my Apache Web Server 01</h1></html>" > index.html
#sudo yum install mysql-server -y
sudo service mysqld start
```

Any thoughts? For context, there's nothing in /var/www/html

Comment: Assuming that's an accurate copy of your script:  There's no space between `echo` and `"`, which means you're trying to run a program that doesn't exist.

Comment: @AnonCoward It's an accurate copy, and after you pointed that out, I thought that may have been the problem all along. Tried it and it still shows "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Test Page" unfortunately.

Comment: How did you try after adjusting the code? via user data or changing it manually ? Note that user data (by default) runs once when your EC2 is launched and not any more.

Comment: @Riz I changed it via user data. Will adjusting it manually via Bash terminal fix it permanently? Because I tried creating a whole new instance with the adjusted code in user data and it was the same result.

Comment: Yes, if it's only one time operation and you do not need to do this for a lot of other servers, you can do all the steps manually by entering into the EC2 via ssh or ssm.

Comment: @Riz so if it wasn't a one time thing and I needed the script to run every time then it would have to be through user data, right? Seems like that's the only little thing I haven't been able to get right. I'm already setting up Route 53 DNS to S3 buckets and all of that stuff so I'm way past this point in my learning but that small glitch still bothers me because I didn't get it all the way right.

Comment: Yes correct. There are two scenarios (which I could think of) where you would like to use user data. 1: You need to create multiple similar instances where you need to have some programs already installed like mysqld, httpd, nginx etc. 2: You have an autoscaling group where you need some stuff already installed/configured. There are other cases as well. Depends on the end user. In your case, you can check the logs and see why it didn't run the first time by checking `/var/log/cloud-init.log`.